# How can I select all <div> without a class or id with rvest?

Tags: css, r, rvest

Take the following HTML snippet, read in with `rvest`:

```
page <- read_html('<div class="author">A name</div>
<div id="tag">A tag</div>
<div>A number</div>
<div>A date</div>
<p class="articleParagraph dearticleParagraph">A text</p>
')
```

I can select all the `<div>` nodes like this:

```
page %>% html_nodes("div")
```

How do I select only those `<div>` nodes that do not have *any* class or id, i.e. not the first two?

---

Building on the first comment, I have made some progress:

```
page %>% html_nodes("div:not([class])")
```

excludes the first div, as desired.

```
page %>% html_nodes("div:not([id])")
```

excludes the second div, as desired.

However, I cannot combine the two:

```
page %>% html_nodes("div:not([class])") %>% html_nodes("div:not([id])")
```

returns an empty node set.

Comment: looks like `page %>% html_nodes("div:not([class])")` should work.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually imprecise in my question. I wanted to exclude both divs with id, and divs with class. However, building on your code, `page %>% html_nodes("div:not([id])") %>% html_nodes("div:not([class])")`returns zero nodes... Any help?

Comment: Changed the question accordingly.

Comment: and `page %>% html_nodes("div:not([id][class])` is also not working  ? or also `page %>% html_nodes("div:not([id] , [class])`

Comment: Unfortunately not: First solution returns all divs, second one throws an error `Expected ')', got ,`

Comment: and `page %>% html_nodes("div:not([id]), div:not([class])` ?? it is supposed to understand css selector if i understand https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rvest/versions/0.3.6/topics/html_nodes

Comment: No :( Returns all divs!

Comment: added the rvest tag to your question ;) , i have no other clues ;)

Comment: Thanks anyway - wanna upvote it so it gets some traction? I'm rather desperate for an answer:/

Comment: last clue : what about a loop ?

Comment: is this what you want? `page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//div[not(contains(@id, "tag") or contains(@class, "author"))]')`

Comment: wait, you wanted a generic version like this I think: `page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//div[not(@id or @class)]')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used xpath with the `not()` function and `or`

```
library(rvest)
page <- read_html('<div class="author">A name</div>
                   <div id="tag">A tag</div>
                   <div>A number</div>
                   <div>A date</div>
                   <p class="articleParagraph dearticleParagraph">A text</p>')

page %>% html_nodes('div')
# {xml_nodeset (4)}
# [1] <div class="author">A name</div>
# [2] <div id="tag">A tag</div>
# [3] <div>A number</div>
# [4] <div>A date</div>

# XPATH version:
page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//div[not(@id or @class)]')
# {xml_nodeset (2)}
# [1] <div>A number</div>
# [2] <div>A date</div>

# CSS version:
page %>% html_nodes('div:not([id]):not([class])')
# {xml_nodeset (2)}
# [1] <div>A number</div>
# [2] <div>A date</div>

# Maybe this is what you are looking for too?
page %>% html_nodes(':not([id]):not([class])')
# {xml_nodeset (3)}
# [1] <body>\n<div class="author">A name</div>\n<div id="tag">A tag</div>\n<div>A number</d ...
# [2] <div>A number</div>
# [3] <div>A date</div>
```

Comment: This is great! Do you have any clue why it does not work with the non-xpath way I tried?

Comment: @broti css version added to answer